# Test if null value in JPA's @ColumnTransformer

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Right now I'm using JPA's @ColumnTransformer to extract characters from the *field* value before inserting it in the DB.

```
@Column(name = "field")
@ColumnTransformer(write = "SUBSTRING(?, 1, 13)")
private String field;
```

Problem is, the value of *field* can be null. How do I go about testing if the value is not null before calling SUBSTRING()?

Would this syntax be correct? I'm using postgresSql.

```
@Column(name = "field")
@ColumnTransformer(write = "CASE ? WHEN IS NOT NULL THEN SUBSTRING(?, 1, 13) ELSE NULL END")
private String field;
```

Thanks.

Comment: DBs treat NULLs not like java: it is safe to use `SUBSTRING(?, 1, 13)` because `SUBSTRING(null,1,13)` returns null.

Comment: And you would be correct. Thank you!